# Find a function f so that Taylor expansion is always accurate to this degree

Tags: taylor-expansion

Find a function $f$ from R to N such that with $T$ be the Taylor expansion of $\sin(x)$ around $0$.

$ | \sin (x) - T_{f(x)}x$| $\leq 1$

The hint is to use $n! \leq 3 \sqrt{n} {(\frac{n}{e})}^n$

Comment: How's $f(x) = \sin (x)$?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake! It's supposed to be Taylor expansion of degree f(x)

Comment: Should that be degree $n$?

Comment: No it's f(x). So the error is always less than 1 no matter where x is

Comment: So you're saying: "At every $x$, can I choose $f(x)$ such that the $f(x)$th Taylor polynomial of $\sin(x)$ evaluated at $x$ differs from $\sin(x)$ by magnitude at most $1$?" Am I reading correctly?

Comment: Yeah! The explanation given is "the precision of Taylor expansion (the number of terms) depends on where x is." Find an f(x) R -> N such that ....

Comment: @Rainroad Are you having trouble applying Taylor's theorem or trouble with finding an explicit value of $n$ for each $x$ (in effect, "solving" for $f(x)$ with quotation marks because many values of $f(x)$ are equally correct)?

Answer (score 0):

So Taylor's theorem* says that if $f$ is smooth (i.e. infinitely differentiable), then $\sin(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} (-1)^{k} \frac{x^{2k + 1}}{(2k + 1)!} + R_{n}(x)$, where $R_{n}(x) = \frac{\sin^{(2n + 3)}(c)}{(2n + 3)!}x^{2k n + 3}$, where $c$ is dependent on $n, x$. But we do know that $|\sin^{(2n + 3)}(c)| \leq 1$, so we have that
\begin{align*}
\left| \sin(x) - \sum_{k = 0}^{n} (-1)^{k} \frac{x^{2k + 1}}{(2k + 1)!} \right| & \leq \frac{|x|^{2n + 3}}{(2n + 3)!} \\
\end{align*}
But more generally, if you have a function that's equal to its (infinite) Taylor series expansion, then by the definition of a limit such an $f(x)$ exists.

Provided here is a way to show $f(x)$ does in fact exist. I don't know how to hide it like a spoiler, so I'm just gonna put it here as a link. If anyone wants to show me how to do the spoiler deal I'd be very appreciative.

http://www.texpaste.com/n/b9vrly1z

*I misspoke, as a commenter pointed out. What I'm more particularly using is the Lagrange form of the remainder. Conveniently, this can still be found on the Wikipedia page on Taylor's theorem.

Comment: Why are the $\sin$ and $\sum$ terms inside the same pair of absolute value signs as $R_n(x)$?  Isn't that quite redundant?

Comment: Quite right. Fixed it.

Comment: Hi! I still don't quite understand. So after we get the LHS is always smaller than the right hand side, how can we find f? Do we set the RHS < 1?

Comment: You say $f(x)$ is such that $|x|^{2f(x) + 3}/(2f(x) + 3)! \leq 1$.

Comment: Is there anyway we can use the hint?

Comment: So I put a link to the solution in the answer. A good hint would be to write out $\frac{|x|^{2n + 3}}{(2n + 3)!} = \frac{|x|}{1} \cdots \frac{|x|}{2n + 3}$, and note that when the denominator gets bigger than $|x|$, the factors become less than $1$ and make the whole thing drop.

Comment: I'm sure there is some way to use the hint, but in my opinion the more obvious and straightforward way to do it is what I put in the answer. Let me know if the solution in the answer is in any way unclear and I can try and explain any weird parts.

Comment: Actually, what you're using is not really Taylor's theorem exactly but exploiting the fact that you have convergence and then using the alternating series error estimate. The Lagrange error gives a somewhat weaker bound.

Comment: OP it should be noted that $\sum_{k = 0}^{n} (-1)^{k} \frac{ x^{2k + 1}}{(2k + 1)!}$ is properly of degree $2n + 1$, so keep that in mind. @Ian what I used is the Lagrange error when it's noted that the $2n + 1$th Taylor polynomial of $\sin$ is also the $2n + 2$th Taylot polynomial of $\sin$. But I did edit for better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to know the degree $n-1$, depending on $x$, where the error is less than $1$. This number is your desired $f(x)$. With this degree, you have the Lagrange error bound of $\frac{|x|^n}{n!}$. It is actually not at all clear how to use your hint here, because you really want a lower bound on $n!$, but your hint gives an upper bound.

One lower bound turns out to be $n^n/e^n$; see http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2011/06/10/stirling-approximation/ So you have an error bound of $\left ( \frac{|x| e}{n} \right )^n$, and you want that to be less than $1$. Solve this inequality by taking a logarithm.